# Is there a way to export current hg repository head in a tar ball

Tags: mercurial, export, archive

HI,

Is there a way to export current hg repository head in a tar ball?
I don't need all the hg meta files in the tar ball (e.g history/diff).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `hg archive -t tgz <targetpath>` to export a clean version as a gzip'd tarball.

Alternatively, you can use a different `-t` flag value to specify a different output type. You can find all of the type (and other) options on the [`hg` man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#archive).

In Mercurial 1.6+, you don't even need to specify the type with `-t` - you can just use `hg archive <targetpath>` and Mercurial will infer the proper type from the filename.

Comment: The next version of Mercurial (version 1.6) will guess the right archive type for you, so `hg archive foo.tar.bz2` is enough to get a bzip2-compressed tarball.

Comment: I think you should update that answer omitting the params... it works nicely with guessing..

Comment: Can this be somehow performed on remote repo?